# Multi-Linked List Implementation

Tags: java, list, data-structures, nodes

I'm trying to implement Multi Linked Lists in Java for a project.

```
package project1;  
import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;
import project1.MLLNode;

class MLList {
    private int nbSets;
    private MLLNode head;

    public MLList(int _nbSets) {
        if (_nbSets <= 0)
            throw(new IllegalArgumentException("- Illegal Number of Sets (" +
      _nbSets + ")!"));
        nbSets = _nbSets;
        head = MLLNode.create(0,null);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(MLLNode.LType ltype) {
        return(head.getNext(ltype) == null);
    }

    public void display(MLLNode.LType ltype) {
       System.out.print("[ ");
        MLLNode node = head.getNext(ltype);
        while(node != null) {
            node.display();
            System.out.print(" ");
            node = node.getNext(ltype);
        }
        System.out.print("]");
    }


    public boolean insert(int id, Object data) {
        MLLNode newnode = MLLNode.create(id, data);
        if(isEmpty(MLLNode.LType.ALL)){
            head.setNext(MLLNode.LType.ALL, newnode);
            newnode.setNext(MLLNode.LType.ALL, null);
        }else{
            MLLNode first = head.getNext(MLLNode.LType.ALL);
            head.setNext(MLLNode.LType.ALL, newnode);
            newnode.setNext(MLLNode.LType.ALL, first);
        }
        if(isEmpty(MLLNode.LType.XOR)){
            head.setNext(MLLNode.LType.XOR, newnode);
            newnode.setNext(MLLNode.LType.XOR, null);
        }else{
            MLLNode first = head.getNext(MLLNode.LType.XOR);
            head.setNext(MLLNode.LType.XOR, newnode);
            newnode.setNext(MLLNode.LType.XOR, first);
        }
        if(isEmpty(MLLNode.LType.ANY)){
            head.setNext(MLLNode.LType.ANY, newnode);
            newnode.setNext(MLLNode.LType.ANY, null);
        }else{
            MLLNode first = head.getNext(MLLNode.LType.ANY);
            head.setNext(MLLNode.LType.ANY, newnode);
            newnode.setNext(MLLNode.LType.ANY, first);
         }
        return true;
    }
}

public Object delete(int id) {
        if (!isEmpty(MLLNode.LType.ALL)){
            MLLNode previous = head;
            MLLNode current = head.getNext(MLLNode.LType.ALL);
            int obj_id = 0;
            while(obj_id != id && current != null){
                previous = current;
                current = current.getNext(MLLNode.LType.ALL);
                obj_id++;
            }
            if (current != null){
                previous.setNext(MLLNode.LType.ALL, current.getNext(MLLNode.LType.ALL));
            }else{
                previous.setNext(MLLNode.LType.ALL, null);
            }
            return current;
        }

        if (!isEmpty(MLLNode.LType.XOR)){
            MLLNode previous = head;
            MLLNode current = head.getNext(MLLNode.LType.XOR);
            int obj_id = 0;
            while(obj_id != id && current != null){
                previous = current;
                current = current.getNext(MLLNode.LType.XOR);
                obj_id++;
            }
            if (current != null){
                previous.setNext(MLLNode.LType.XOR, current.getNext(MLLNode.LType.XOR));
            }else{
                previous.setNext(MLLNode.LType.XOR, null);
            }
            return current;
        }

        if (!isEmpty(MLLNode.LType.ANY)){
            MLLNode previous = head;
            MLLNode current = head.getNext(MLLNode.LType.ANY);
            int obj_id = 0;
            while(obj_id != id && current != null){
                previous = current;
                current = current.getNext(MLLNode.LType.ANY);
                obj_id++;
            }
            if (current != null){
                previous.setNext(MLLNode.LType.ANY, current.getNext(MLLNode.LType.ANY));
            }else{
                previous.setNext(MLLNode.LType.ANY, null);
            }
            return current;
        }

        return null;

              }



public Object find(MLLNode.LType ltype, int id) {

    }
```

We are given this code and we created the methods insert,delete and we're about to create find.
We are also given the node constructor as it is presented below in the comment:

```
package project1;
import java.util.EnumMap;

class MLLNode {

    public enum LType {ANY, ALL, XOR};
    public int count;
    public int id;
    public Object data;

    private EnumMap<LType,MLLNode> next;

    private MLLNode(int _id, Object _data) {
        id = _id;
        data = _data;
        count = 0;
        next = new EnumMap<LType,MLLNode>(LType.class);
        next.put(LType.ANY,null);
        next.put(LType.ALL,null);
        next.put(LType.XOR,null);
    }

    public static MLLNode create(int _id, Object _data) {
        return(new MLLNode(_id,_data));
    }

    public MLLNode getNext(LType ltype) {
        return(next.get(ltype));
    }

    public MLLNode setNext(LType ltype, MLLNode ref) {
        next.put(ltype, ref);
        return(ref);
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.print(id + " (" + count + ")");
    }
}
```

Now our lists are ANY,ALL and XOR.
When we insert a node if the counter hits 1 it goes with the ANY list when hits 2 it disconnects from the list,when it hits 3 it connects with the ALL list,when it hits 4 it disconnects and when it hits 5 connects with XOR.
When we delete a node if the counter hits 0 it deletes the node and if the counter hits one of the above numbers it just does what it does in insert method.
How can we make use of the counter in the MLList Class so we can reach the limitations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please check the FAQ [ask] on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. You should at least have tried something yourself and ideally show some **code** of what **you** have tried (not just boilerplate code from your exercise)

Comment: Thanks for the advice sir! :)
I agree with the point you've made but I just need an idea.
Not the code itself :)

Comment: I made some progress here but I'm stuck with this one :/
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with "you are stuck"? What works? What doesn't work? What do you expect the non-working parts to do and what do they do instead?

Comment: It runs and it shows something like :
- ANY: [ 9 (0) 8 (0) 4 (0) 10 (0) 14 (0) 10 (0) 6 (0) 3 (0) 19 (0) 15 (0) 18 (0) ]
- ALL: [ 9 (0) 8 (0) 4 (0) 10 (0) 14 (0) 10 (0) 6 (0) 3 (0) 19 (0) 15 (0) 18 (0) ]
- XOR: [ 9 (0) 8 (0) 4 (0) 10 (0) 14 (0) 10 (0) 6 (0) 3 (0) 19 (0) 15 (0) 18 (0) ]

I created an MLListApp whick displays the lists...but in here () I need it to show the counter value